# OpenCV : Memory leak while using QPixmap

Tags: memory-leaks, video-streaming, pyside, python-3.4, qpixmap

I am trying to video stream from a 1920x1080 HD camera with 60fps,using opencv. The issue is not with the streaming but the memory leak, I am losing almost 6GB of my memory within the first minute of streaming. Please help me how to stop this.

```
  from PySide.QtCore import *
  from PySide.QtGui import *
  import cv2
  import sys

  class MainApp(QWidget):

      def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.video_size = QSize(1920, 1080)
        self.setup_ui()
        self.setup_camera()

    def setup_ui(self):
        """Initialize widgets.
        """
        self.image_label = QLabel()
        self.image_label.setFixedSize(self.video_size)

        self.quit_button = QPushButton("Quit")
        self.quit_button.clicked.connect(self.close)

        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.image_label)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.quit_button)

        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

    def setup_camera(self):
        """Initialize camera.
        """
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, self.video_size.width())
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, self.video_size.height())

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.display_video_stream)
        self.timer.start(30)

    def display_video_stream(self):
        """Read frame from camera and repaint QLabel widget.
        """
        _, frame = self.capture.read()
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0],
                   frame.strides[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainApp()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**EDIT**

I found where the memory leak is **self.timer.start(30)** If I increase the time call , the memory leak is slower. Any suggestions how to stop the memory leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone having the same issue, please import qimage2ndarray this library and add
the following changes to the function display_video_stream

```
    def display_video_stream(self):
    """Read frame from camera and repaint QLabel widget.
    """

    _, frame = self.capture.read()

    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    # frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    image = qimage2ndarray.array2qimage(frame) #Solution for memory leak
    self.image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
```